# what is the equivalence of C++ 1i64 Shifting in C#

Tags: c#, c++, migration, bit-shift

I am working on some C++ code and I need to translate it into C# , in the original code there is this line :

```
if(!(Bchild[j>>6] & (1i64 << (j % 64))))
```

Where j is some number < 10000. And Bchild is a UInt64

In C# I couldn't find any equivalent to 1i64 however , I improvised and I thought its ok to rewrite the code like this :

```
if ((Bchild[j >> 6] & Convert.ToUInt64((1 << (j % 64)))) == 0)
```

Now I get an error : value is too large or too small. My first part question is : Am I doing it right ? if so , then : what is the C# equivalent for 1i64 ? because I think this is the main problem of having this runtime error

Notice : I am working on 64X operating System and **when execution approaches 62,63,64 then (1 << (j % 64))) gives this such numbers : 9223372036854775808**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I doing it right ?

No. `Convert.ToUInt64((1 << (j % 64))` converts *the result* of shifting, not the argument.

> what is the C# equivalent for 1i64

You may use `1L` instead of `1i64`, or `1UL` instead of `1ui64`.

BTW, be aware that in some cases left shifting of signed integers in `C++` is undefined behavior. (Your concrete case is OK according to the latest standard, assuming that `1i64 << 63` is representable in the corresponding unsigned type.)

Comment: I tried both , still not working ... see this Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToUInt64((1L << (63 % 64))));

Comment: `1UL` instead of `1L` would work. In your case, `Convert` fails since the argument is negative. And you do not need to convert anyway.